# How to trigger a revision for a custom method from a Controller?

Tags: laravel, revisionable

When using the [RevisionableTrait](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable/blob/master/src/Venturecraft/Revisionable/RevisionableTrait.php), how can you trigger it to save a revision for a specific model, all this done from a Controller.

An user sends an email (this action doesn't CRUD any model), but I want to track this action. So I do something like:
`Action::make('send email', $user, $email, $time, $from, $to, $subject, ....)`

---

Reason: I want to save the revision when doing something other that the CRUD methods that Revisionable supports. So, I need to trigger it manually.

Example:
[This package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog) does exactly what I am describing. I can create an Activity whenever is needed. Plus appending some extra information.

Example: I want to create a revision even if the Model doesn't changes!. Some actions that could trigger this could be: a user sends an email, a user looks at an email draft. So, from the Controller I need to log/register that action and save it. Is that possible?

[Revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) looks like it doesn't have an event listening to custom triggers. Am I wrong ?, is there a workaround ?

**Notes:**

- Maybe I'm using the wrong library. Cause I also want to save actions that doesn't edit (create, update, delete) the model. I mean, I want to save that some actions where made, even if they didn't modify the model, instead they just used it.
- Same question for [another package](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/revisionable/issues/58).

Comment: Are you asking how to save a revision with the linked package?

Comment: @Samsquanch how to do it in [this package](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable)?

Answer (score 0):

[The revisionable documentation](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) tells you exactly what you need to do, add the trait to your model:

```
class YourModelHere extends Eloquent {

    use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    // other model code goes here
}
```

It woks by calling [boot methods when saving, saved, creating, and updating.](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable/blob/master/src/Venturecraft/Revisionable/RevisionableTrait.php#L68)

Is also provides events that you can tie into:

> Events
>
> Every time a model revision is created an event is fired. You can
>   listen for `revisionable.created`, `revisionable.saved` or
>   `revisionable.deleted`.

Comment: I updated my question. I think I wasn't clear enough. I want to log even if the model doesn't gets modified.

Comment: Why not just call `save()` on it even if it's not modified? This should create a new revision.